# Mouse lag when popup open

Tags: popup, mouse, lag, android-things

I am using android things 1.0.3 on RPI3 with HDMI screen (1920x1080) and usb mouse.
When I open a new popup window using new Dialog() the mouse cursor is lagging.
When using mouse on main screen there is no problem.
Using usbhid-mousepoll=0  and harwareAccelerated=true doesn't change anything.